# Convert unix time human readable loop

Tags: bash

I have a variable called `$time` that contains

```
1,1708746085,apples,cars
2,1709764378,pears,bus
3,1709875892,orange,truck
```

I'm trying to iterate over the variable and convert the time 2nd column from unix time to human readable

```
var=`echo $time |awk -F ","' '{print $2}'`
for secs in $var
do date -d @$secs
done
```

But it only seems to convert the 1st occurrence and not all of them.   Suggestion?

At the end of the day I'm hoping to append the converted times to the end of items as the 5th column like

```
1,170874608,apples,cars,Fri Mar 15 2024 7:37:39 PM
```

Comment: Variable references should almost always be double-quoted; use `echo "$time"` instead of `echo "$time"`. Without the double-quote, the value gets mangled in various ways which, in this case, collapse the entire variable into a single line. See ["When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting mistakes like this, so I recommend running your script through it and fixing what it points out.

Comment: `echo "$time" | gawk '$2{print $0,strftime("%a %b %-d %Y %l:%M:%S %p",$2)}' FS=, OFS=,` ?

Comment: `awk -F, '{print $2}' <<< "$time" | while read secs; do date -d @$secs; done`

Comment: Try this: very quick as this run `date` only once: `sed < file.csv 's/^[0-9]*,\([0-9]\+\),.*/@\1/'|LANG=C date -f -| paste -d, file.csv -`

Comment: Or, from *variable `$time`*:  `sed <<<"$time" 's/^[0-9]*,\([0-9]\+\),.*/@\1/'|LANG=C date -f -| paste -d, <(echo "$time") -`

Comment: Or even `paste -d, - <<<"$time" <(sed <<<"$time" 's/^[0-9]*,\([0-9]\+\),.*/@\1/'|LANG=C date -f -)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *homage* to [pjh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78171801/8656552)'s brillant reminder that `printf` can do the date conversion *internally* in 4.2+, one with no `read` that uses pure `bash` regex parsing. :)

```
data="$time"
line=$'^\n{0,1}([0-9]),([0-9]{10}),([a-z]+,[a-z]+)'
while [[ "$data" =~ $line ]]
do printf "%s,%s,%s,%(%a %b %d %Y %r)T\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"
   data="${data#${BASH_REMATCH[0]}}"
done
```

You *could* just let the `awk` format the `date` calls.
As pointed out, it does leave a certain possibility of injection if you aren't **100%** sure of your inputs. Please be careful.

```
$: echo "$time" | awk -F, -v OFS=, '$2~/^[0-9]{10}$/{ system("date +\""$0",%a %b %d %Y %r\" -d @"$2) }'
1,1708746085,apples,cars,Fri Feb 23 2024 09:41:25 PM
2,1709764378,pears,bus,Wed Mar 06 2024 04:32:58 PM
3,1709875892,orange,truck,Thu Mar 07 2024 11:31:32 PM
```

Obviously you could add error checking and such to make it more robust, but if you're going to use `awk` anyway, [oguz ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78170706/8656552)'s is better.

The same general idea in a more prosaic loop -

```
$: echo "$time" | while IFS=, read -ra line; do printf %s, "${line[@]}"
; date +"%a %b %d %Y %r" -d "@${line[1]}"; done
1,1708746085,apples,cars,Fri Feb 23 2024 09:41:25 PM
2,1709764378,pears,bus,Wed Mar 06 2024 04:32:58 PM
3,1709875892,orange,truck,Thu Mar 07 2024 11:31:32 PM
```

Comment: it may be safer to do `"date ... -d @"$2 | getline s; print $0,s` so there is no opportunity for injection issues (and assuming `$2` has also been sanitised)

Comment: Perhaps use ` awk -F, -v OFS=, '$2~/^[0-9]{10}$/ { system...` for an injection check.

Comment: Given the minimal parsing needed, I think this is a case where it's better to let the shell split the line than to try to safely embed a shell command into an `awk` script.

Comment: To give credit where it is due, the first suggestion to use the `%(fmt)T` specifier with `printf` was in a [comment by oguz ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78170444/convert-unix-time-human-readable-loop#comment137812302_78170836).

Comment: Thanks for all the excellent input. I'm trying the same approach to convert byes to mb like this below but maybe my approach is not so correct                                        MB=`while IFS= read -r line ;  do 'numfmt --to=iec'; done <<< "$bytes`

Comment: Tried this for loop but not getting expected output for by in "${bytes[@]}" ; do
 echo "$by"| numfmt --to=iec
done

Comment: Actually nevermind, all good thx again

Answer (score 4):

If you've got Bash 4.2 (released in 2011) or later, try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure Bash code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

time='1,1708746085,apples,cars
2,1709764378,pears,bus
3,1709875892,orange,truck'

while IFS=, read -r first utime rest; do
    printf '%s,%s,%s,%(%c)T\n' "$first" "$utime" "$rest" "$utime"
done <<<"$time"
```

- The `%(fmt)T` specifier for the `printf` built-in was introduced in Bash 4.2. It causes `printf` to output the date-time string resulting from using `fmt` as a format string for [strftime](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html).
- See the [Here Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) section in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) for an explanation of `<<<"$time"`.
- See [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for an explanation of the `while IFS=, read -r ...` loop.

Comment: Pure [tag:bash] too, could be quicker as doesn't use any loop: `mapfile -t lines <<<"$time";times=(${lines[@]#*,});printf -v fmt '%%s,%(%c)T\n' ${times[@]%%,*};printf "$fmt" "${lines[@]}"`

Comment: Variant, using *`extglob`*: `time+=$'\n';mapfile -t times <<<"${time//,*([!,]),*([!,])$'\n'/$'\n'}";printf -v fmt '%%s,%(%c)T\n' ${times[@]#*,};(IFS=$'\n'; printf "$fmt" $time)`

Comment: Awesome everybody, thanks 

Comment: One last thing, is there a conversion that fmt handles ms rather sec, i have some cases where the times will look like 1708746085000 rather than sec 1708746085. Thanks again really appreciate it.

Comment: @bobmonty, the `%(fmt)T` conversions only handle an integer number of seconds.  They can't handle milliseconds or fractional seconds.  You could use Bash arithmetic to convert milliseconds to seconds (e.g. `"$((utime_ms/1000))"`).

Comment: Dumb question, can that get evaluated directly in the printf like?

printf %s,%s,%s,"$((utime/1000))" $first"$utime" "$rest" "$utime"
done <<<"$time"

Comment: @bobmonty, it's generally not a good idea to put variable expansions in the `printf` format string, and [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will normally complain if you do it.  I'd go with `printf '%s,%s,%s,%(%c)T\n' "$first" "$utime" "$rest" "$((utime/1000))"`

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford writing `$time` to a file, there is a much simpler way:

```
awk -F, '{print "@"$2}' file | date -f - | paste -d, file -
```

Answer (score 2):

For a pure bash solution you can read line by line with a `while` loop feeding the loop with a *process substitution*. You modify the *internal field separator* (`IFS`) to only break on `','` or `'\n'` (or just add `','` to the default `IFS` in your case).

A short example would be:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

v='1,1708746085,apples,cars
2,1709764378,pears,bus
3,1709875892,orange,truck'

while IFS=$',\n' read -r n t f c; do
  printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" "$n" "$t" "$f" "$c" "$(date -d @"$t")"
done < <(printf "%s\n" "$v")
```

Where `v` is your variable, `n` holds the field-1 number, `t` holds the time, `f` holds the fruit and `c` holds the cars (not very creative)

(adjust the `date` format as desired, perhaps  `$(date -d @"$t" +'%F %T')` or the like)

You can also use a *heredoc* to feed the `while` loop, e.g.

```bash
while IFS=$',\n' read -r n t f c; do
  printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" "$n" "$t" "$f" "$c" "$(date -d @"$t")"
done << EOF
$v
EOF
```

**Example Use/Output**

With the script in `tmp/t.sh` you can do:

```
$ bash tmp/t.sh
1,1708746085,apples,cars,Fri Feb 23 09:41:25 PM CST 2024
2,1709764378,pears,bus,Wed Mar  6 04:32:58 PM CST 2024
3,1709875892,orange,truck,Thu Mar  7 11:31:32 PM CST 2024
```

(note: output with my LOCALE and timezone info)

Comment: A *pure bash solution* would probably use `printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%(%c)T\n" "$n" "$t" "$f" "$c" "$t"`.

Comment: Good observation. I must be falling behind in my old age `:)`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Ruby to do that:

```
#!/bin/bash

time='1,1708746085,apples,cars
2,1709764378,pears,bus
3,1709875892,orange,truck'

echo "$time" | ruby -F, -r "time" -lane '
puts "#{$F.join(",")},#{Time.at($F[1].to_i).strftime("%c")}"'
```

(The `strftime("%c")` formats to the preferred local time output and is OS configuration dependent.)

Prints:

```
1,1708746085,apples,cars,Fri Feb 23 22:41:25 2024
2,1709764378,pears,bus,Wed Mar  6 17:32:58 2024
3,1709875892,orange,truck,Fri Mar  8 00:31:32 2024
```

Notice that each answer here has a different time in the example output. Epoch time is 'naive' meaning that the OS local time zone is assumed. You will need to add time zone info if you want that to be the same across different time zones...